# How to grab a chunk of data from a file?

Tags: python

I want to grab a chunk of data from a file. I know the start line and the end line. I wrote the code but its incomplete and I don't know how to solve it further.

```
file = open(filename,'r')
    end_line='### Leave a comment!'
star_line = 'Kill the master'
    for line in file:
            if star_line in line:   
        ??
```

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite-state_machine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
startmarker = "ohai"
endmarker = "meheer?"
marking = False
result = []

with open("somefile") as f:
  for line in f:
    if line.startswith(startmarker): marking = True
    elif line.startswith(endmarker): marking = False

    if marking: result.append(line)

if len(result) > 1:
  print "".join(result[1:])
```

**Explanation:** The `with` block is a nice way to use files -- it makes sure you don't forget to `close()` it later. The `for` walks each line and:

- starts outputting when it sees a line that starts with `'ohai'` (including that line)
- stops outputting when it sees a line that starts with `'meheer?'` (without outputting that line).

After the loop, `result` contains the part of the file that is needed, plus that initial marker. Rather than making the loop more complicated to ignore the marker, I just throw it out using a slice: `result[1:]` returns all elements in `result` starting at index 1; in other words, it excludes the first element (index 0).

**Update to reflect add partial-line matches:**

```
startmarker = "ohai"
endmarker = "meheer?"
marking = False
result = []

with open("somefile") as f:
  for line in f:
    if not marking:
      index = line.find(startmarker)
      if index != -1:
        marking = True
        result.append(line[index:])
    else:
      index = line.rfind(endmarker)
      if index != -1:
        marking = False
        result.append(line[:index + len(endmarker)])
      else:
        result.append(line)

print "".join(result)
```

**Yet more explanation:** `marking` still tells us whether we should be outputting whole lines, but I've changed the `if` statements for the start and end markers as follows:

- if we're not (yet) marking, and we see the `startmarker`, then output the current line *starting at the marker*. The `find` method returns the position of the first occurrence of `startmarker` in this case. The `line[index:]` notation means 'the content of `line` starting at position `index`.
- while marking, just output the current line entirely *unless* it contains `endmarker`. Here, we use `rfind` to find the rightmost occurrence of `endmarker`, and the `line[...]` notation means 'the content of `line` up to position `index` (the start of the match) plus the marker itself.' Also: stop marking now :)

Comment: @phooji Thanx for your reply but my question is little different. Suppose you have this data in file "hi My name is tau tau and I live in dfo". Now start = name and end = live. SO my reuired output will be name is tau tau and I live.

Comment: @phooji Awesome, it works. Can you explain it a little bit. Thanx a lot

Comment: @phooji Thanx for that, one more quick question. While running the code I am getting encodingerror, and I know its because of file. Can you tell me a way to pass by this error or compiler ignore it.

Comment: @jack: That's a separate question, and it's been answered elsewhere on this site. See here for example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1524262/why-do-i-get-encoding-error-in-python-warnings-formatwarning-on-format-string .

Answer (score 0):

if reading the whole file is not a problem, I would use `file.readlines()` to read in all the lines in a list of strings.

then you can use `list_of_lines.index(value)` to find the indices of the first and last line, and then select all the lines between these two indices.

Comment: ... which can be done using slices (ie: `lines[start:end]` ) and then just join them back together

Comment: This will fail spectacularly if the last line shows up before the first line.

Comment: Not if there's another end line after the start line.

Answer (score 0):

First, a test file (assuming Bash shell):

```
for i in {0..100}; do  echo "line $i"; done > test_file.txt
```

That generates a file a 101 line file with lines `line 0\nline 1\n` ... `line 100\n`

This Python script captures the line between and including `mark1` up to and not including `mark2`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

mark1 = "line 22"
mark2 = "line 26"
record=False
error=False
buf = []

with open("test_file.txt") as f:
  for line in f:
    if mark1==line.rstrip(): 
        if error==False and record==False: 
            record=True

    if mark2==line.rstrip(): 
        if record==False:
            error=True
        else:
            record=False

    if record==True and error==False: 
        buf.append(line)

if len(buf) > 1 and error==False:
    print "".join(buf)
else:
    print "There was an error in there..."
```

Prints:

```
line 22
line 23
line 24
line 25
```

in this case. If both marks are not found in the correct sequence, it will print an error.

If the size of the file between the marks is excessive, you may need some additional logic. You can also use a regex for each line instead of an exact match if that fits your use case.