# Error in Python Code that Generates XML using nltk

Tags: python, xml, nltk

I'm generating some XML code with Python. This code counts the number of occurrences of a word in a corpus and matches that word to a number (a probability distribution from an NLTK corpus).

Here's a sample a little of the XML that I'd like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
    <root>
    <Durapipe type="int">1</Durapipe>
    <EXPLAIN type="int">2</EXPLAIN>
    <woods type="int">2</woods>
    <hanging type="int">3</hanging>
    <hastily type="int">2</hastily>
    <key type="int" name="27p">1</key>
    <localized type="int">1</localized>
    <Schuster type="int">5</Schuster>
    <regularize type="int">1</regularize>
    ....
    </root>
```

Here's the Python I'm using to generate this:

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals

import nltk.corpus
from nltk import FreqDist
from dicttoxml import dicttoxml, xml_escape

#corpus
words = [w.decode('utf-8', errors='replace') for w in nltk.corpus.reuters.words()]
fd = FreqDist(words)
afd = {xml_escape(k):v for k,v in fd.items()}

# special key for sum
afd['__sum__']=fd.N()

xml = dicttoxml(afd)

f=open('frequencies.xml', 'w')
f.write(xml)
f.close()
```

Unfortunately, Python doesn't like this. I'm getting the following error:

```
UnicodeEncodeError                        Traceback (most recent call last)
C:canopylibrarylocation\site-packages\IPython\utils\py3compat.pyc in execfile(fname, glob, loc)
    195             else:
    196                 filename = fname
--> 197             exec compile(scripttext, filename, 'exec') in glob, loc
    198     else:
    199         def execfile(fname, *where):

C:\locationoffile\freq2xml.py in <module>()
      6 
      7 #corpus
----> 8 words = [w.decode('utf-8', errors='replace') for w in nltk.corpus.reuters.words()]
      9 fd = FreqDist(words)
     10 afd = {xml_escape(k):v for k,v in fd.items()}

C:\Users\David Naber\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\App\appdata\canopy-1.4.1.1975.win-x86_64\lib\encodings\utf_8.pyc in decode(input, errors)
     14 
     15 def decode(input, errors='strict'):
---> 16     return codecs.utf_8_decode(input, errors, True)
     17 
     18 class IncrementalEncoder(codecs.IncrementalEncoder):

UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xfc' in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)
```

My code used to actually generate XML, but I was having a problem with nltk.corpus.reuters.words() returning a list of words - of which, not all could be valid XML names, because some were periods, commas, or slashes. I tried modifying my code to fix this, and now I'm left with the above error.

Any feedback you can give would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/1524262/3001761. This is really nothing to do with XML and NLTK.

Comment: Wait...I'm confused by this answer. What do you suggest that I do?

Comment: Figure out where the `'ü'` is coming from and how to deal with it. See e.g. https://docs.python.org/2/howto/unicode.html